# ggplot2 abline out of the plot boundary

Tags: r, ggplot2

When I adding an abline (y = 1.5x), it's drawn out off the boundary of the plot layout.
See the orange dash line extends out off the plot.
How can I fix it?

```
data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = get(TetTable[i,"chnl1"]), y = get(TetTable[i,"chnl2"]))) +
  geom_point(aes(x = get(TetTable[i,"chnl1"]), y = get(TetTable[i,"chnl2"])), alpha = 0.5, size = 0.1, show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_hex(bins = 128, colour = "gray", show.legend = FALSE) +
  stat_smooth(method = "lm") +
  
  geom_point(data = subset(data, get(paste0(TetTable[i,"Tet"],"_Boolean")) == "P"), alpha = 1, size = 2, colour = "red") + 
  stat_ellipse(data = subset(data, get(paste0(TetTable[i,"Tet"],"_Boolean")) == "P"), alpha = 1, colour = "red") +
  
  geom_point(data = subset(data, get(paste0(TetTable[i,"Tet"],"_lmCutoff")) < 1), alpha = 1, size = 2, colour = "blue", shape = 17) + 
  # stat_ellipse(data = subset(data, get(paste0(TetTable[i,"Tet"],"_lmCutoff")) == "P"), alpha = 1, colour = "blue") +
  
  geom_point(data = subset(data, get(paste0(TetTable[i,"Tet"],"_Final")) == "P"), alpha = 1, size = 2, colour = "orange") + 
  stat_ellipse(data = subset(data, get(paste0(TetTable[i,"Tet"],"_Final")) == "P"), alpha = 1, colour = "orange") +

  geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = c(1, 1.5, 1/1.5), linetype = c("solid","dashed", "dashed"), color = c("blue", "orange", "orange")) +
  
  scale_x_continuous(TetTable[i,"chnl1"],
                     trans = "asinh",
                     limits = c(1, 10^5, 10),
                     breaks = c(1,10,100,1000,10000,100000),
                     labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x))) +
  scale_y_continuous(TetTable[i,"chnl2"],
                     trans = "asinh", 
                     limits = c(1, 10^5, 10),
                     breaks = c(1,10,100,1000,10000,100000),
                     labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x)))+
  annotation_logticks(sides = "bl", outside = TRUE) +
  annotation_logticks(sides = "bl", outside = TRUE) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off")
```

[image]

Comment: That's because you use `coord_cartesian(clip = "off")`. Switching to `on` should solve your issue.

Comment: But I wanna have log scales on the axis. Any suggestion?

Comment: In that case you could add the lines via geom_line and set values which fall outside of the limits to NA. But be aware that ggplot2 exapnds the scale on each side by 5 percent so that this apporach probably requires to set `expand = c(0, 0)` in scale_y_... and to add the exapnsion manually by extending the limits by 5 percent